# can't change the properties of h tags

Tags: html, css, ruby

Why can't I change the properties of my h tags, like the color, font size and family, position, etc?

Here is the html.erb code:

```
<h2style="font-family:arial;">Account summary </h2><br>
<h2style="font-family:arial;"> Name : <%=  @user.first_name %> </h2<br>
<br><h3style="font-family:arial;"> Middle initial : <%=  @user.middle_initial %> </h3><br>
 <h4style="font-family:arial;"> Last name : <%=  @user.last_name %> </h4><br>          <h5style="font-family:arial;"> E-mail : <%=  @user.email %> </h5><br>
```

And here is css:

```
 h2, h3
   {
    color:green;
    font-size: 32px;
   }
```

Comment: you clearly haven't done any research work before coming here, or you would have noticed the missing spaces and other characters in your code

Comment: Whenever your markup/styles/etc. aren't rendering as expected, the most useful tool you can find is the W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org  It would have a few things to point out in your markup.

Comment: ...and you **really** shouldn't be using `<br>` tags for spacing.

Comment: edit your question to reflect changes you've made and the current state of the code/question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <h2><font face="arial" color="green">This is some text!</font> </h2>
```

Comment: That worked, how come? And can I change the size of the font like this also?

Comment: Yes just insert size="32" in the font tag, let me know if it works

Comment: It works, can I add size and border in the font tag?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by size and border, you want to add a border around the text ?

Comment: As you can see, my h tags are beneath each other.. and when the view is shown, there is a large spacing between each h tag, how can I minimize that spacing?

Comment: Just delete the <br> that should do it !

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect:

```
<h2style="font-family:arial;">
```

Correct:

```
<h2 style="font-family:arial;">
```

you're forgot whitespace.

The css style declared in file or html will be ignored by used in style attribute

Answer (score 0):

Because right now you have a style in the same tag as your h2. Plus your h2 tag is called h2style, there is no space inbetween

Comment: When I add the space, then it doesn't change the font to the one I declared in the tag.

Comment: What you need to do is put your style elements inside your h2 CSS style sheet instead of having 2 different styles

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a space between the tag and style property. This should fix your troubles

```
<h2 style="font-family:arial;">Account summary </h2>
```

However it is generally good practice to put all styles together in the CSS. So this:

HTML

```
<h2>Account summary </h2><br>
<h2> Name : <%=  @user.first_name %> </h2<br>
<br><h3> Middle initial : <%=  @user.middle_initial %> </h3><br>
<h4> Last name : <%=  @user.last_name %> </h4><br>
<h5> E-mail : <%=  @user.email %> </h5><br>
```

CSS

```
h2, h3
   {
    font-family: arial, helvetica, san-serif;
    color: green;
    font-size: 32px;
   }
```

Comment: I tried everything, and still it doesn't do nothing. Not to mention trying to move this stuff around the page.